# Redirection with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect from:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/historical/category
```

to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/category
```

How can I do it with .htaccess?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using something like

> Redirect /historical/category/index.html
>   http://www.mydomain.com/category

see more [here](http://www.htaccessredirect.co.uk/)